# Changes of "lifetime" under "system.runtime.remoting" in Web.config are not being applied

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, remoting, .net-remoting

According to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20080906214332/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300474.aspx) article, the `LifetimeServices` properties (`LeaseTime`, `RenewOnCallTime` etc.) can be changed in the application configuration like this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.runtime.remoting>
      <application>
         <lifetime 
          leaseTime = "10M" 
          sponsorshipTimeOut = "1M"
          renewOnCallTime = "15M" 
          LeaseManagePollTime = "8s"
         />
      </application>
   </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

In my ASP.NET web application hosted in IIS, I have extended the Web.config according to this example by adding a "system.runtime.remoting" section inside the "configuration" section. However, for some reason my values are never applied and the default values (e.g. five minutes for the `LeaseTime` property) are used. I also tried to create a new "app.config" file in the same directory but this also did not work. What am I doing wrong and how can I force my application to use the values from the configuration instead of the default values?